# Alt Key triggeres keyup() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  $(this).val('Alt');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

In the `keyup()` function, It is always triggered after pressing `Alt` key twice, Why does that happen And how to prevent it?

Comment: It doesn't happen when you press the Alt key only once? Also note that `keyup` is triggered when you release the press.

Comment: `Alt` triggers `keyup` because `Alt` is a key. So do `Ctrl` and `Shift`. (And they trigger it the *first* time, too.)

Comment: @DeepakKamat It doesn't happen when i press once, In `Firefox`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do i check if the pressed keys are from letters and numbers only?

Comment: So what's the issue? Do you want the `Alt` key to trigger the function or not? The title of the question makes me think that you don't want the function to execute when the key being pressed is `Alt` so it doesn't matter if it is only once or twice.

Comment: Are ppl so brain watched by solving everything with jQuery? use `this.value = 'Alt'`

Comment: @DeepakKamat I understand now, Then i have to define what keys are allowed and what isn't When i use `keyup()`

Comment: `event` provides you information about the `keyup` event that was triggered so you can write you logic using the info. it provides. In your case you can use `event.which`, it will return the  `keyCode` / `charCode` of the key. `Alt` is `18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alt` key from my observations seem to be detected by the events `keyup` and `keydown`, but on `keypress` the `alt` key is not detected as an event. In our scenario we use `keyup` hence the event is fired!

Hence what you can do is handle certain keys from triggering the main event by  using the below code, the details and for more details on [char codes](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) visit the link!

```js
$('input').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode != 18) {
    $(this).val('Alt');
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Comment: *"The alt key is also counted as a keypress"* Unfortunate phrasing, and `Alt` on its own *doesn't* trigger the `keypress` event. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I have updated my answer! please do check the validity of my statement!

Comment: @NarenMurali `event` isn't defined as the function name too, But the answer is still helpful.

Comment: @NarenMurali Yes, Works perfectly now. And i understood what to do from it as intended.

Comment: @Matheo Glad it did!

Comment: @NarenMurali: I had a typo in my comment which may have made it hard to understand, it was meant to end with *"... **as** `Alt` on its own..."*. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, but I understood the gist of your comment and made corrections for the same! Thanks again!